# Does fast enumeration in Objective-C guarantee the order of iteration?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, iteration, fast-enumeration

Can I expect it to go from the start of an array to the end in order? Can't find anything in the docs about this.

i.e. is

```
for (id val in array)
{
   NSLog(@"%@", val);
}
```

always going to print out the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i)
{
   NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From Apples' [Objective-C documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) on fast enumeration:

> For collections or enumerators that have a well-defined order—such as NSArray  or NSEnumerator instance derived from an array—the enumeration proceeds in that order, so simply counting iterations will give you the proper index into the collection if you need it.

Comment: The corollary is that collections with undefined order (i.e. `NSSet` and `NSDictionary`) have an undefined iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

Once again I've found the answer right after posting. My old reference didn't mention the order of iteration, but the online one did. The array is indeed iterated in order.