# Is NSArray for-loop enumeration order guaranteed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, nsarray

Pretty straightforward question here: is the enumeration order in a `for` loop guaranteed to follow the order of an NSArray target (i.e. start at object index 0 and increment by 1 each time)?

Specifically, is the enumeration order in the following code snippet guaranteed to start at array index 0 and increment by 1 each loop? (`codesArray` is an NSArray)

```
for (NSNumber *num in codesArray) {
    // do stuff //
}
```

Or if I want to guarantee enumeration order do I have to do a traditional `for` loop of the style:

```
for (int i=0; i<[codesArray count]; i++) {
    // do stuff //
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, these will follow a guaranteed order as you would expect.

Comment: Answer here (to same question) has the same conclusion, with a link to Apple's documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777629/189687